# How to get query string value in client side after page upload using Django and Python

Tags: javascript, python, django

I need to fetch the the query string value from URL on the client side and that URL is passed from Django template. I am explaining my code below.

> base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {% load static %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Nuclear Reactor</h1>
      {% if count > 0  %}
      <b>Hi, {{ user.username }}</b>
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}?file=//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.5.0/velocity.min.js">Home</a>
        <a href="{% url 'view_reactor' %}?file=//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.5.0/velocity.min.js">View Reactor status</a>
        <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a>
      {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a> / <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">signup</a>
      {% endif %}
      <hr>
    </header>
    <main>
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here I am passing some query string value for `home.html` loading.

> home.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<center><h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>This App allow to control the life cycle of the Nuclear Reactor and Retrive the status report </p>
<p><a href="{% url 'status' %}">Status report</a><a href="{% url 'control' %}">Control panel</a></p>
</center>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){

    }
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

I need to fetch the query string using JavaScript when the home page rendered.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in the client side, I think you can use javascript location object:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
        querystring = location.search;
        // do something
    }
</script>
```

Otherwise, you can get the parameters from the request in the server side (in the view) and inject the object to the template.